# Create a 3D bar chart in NetBeans to display top 10 items in a database

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I have developed a small application that must show the top ten selling items for a company using a 3D bar graph. The items will be retrieved from a mysql database.

I do understand how to retrieve data from a mysql database, but how do I get it to work with the bar graph on Neteans?

How can I go about achieving this or where is the best resource to help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way of going about this is firstly establishing your database connection with the following coding as shown below:

```
  //connects to the database
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection)
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBName","root","password");
        //select statement calling data from the sales database
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM dbsales ORDER BY usold DESC LIMIT 10");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

An then you will needs to use the following coding for the creation and display of the chart in netbeans

```
//creates the graph object
        DefaultCategoryDataset ddataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            //retrieves data from the database for the graph
            ddataset.setValue(new Double(rs.getDouble("usold")), rs.getString("pbrand")  + " " + rs.getString("pname"),  rs.getString("pid"));
        }
         //generates the graph
         JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("Top 10 Selling Products", "Products", "Number of Units Sold", ddataset);
         //creates the graph title
        chart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.RED);
        //plots the graph
        CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.BLUE);
        //creates the frame 
        ChartFrame frame2 = new ChartFrame("Top 10 Selling Products", chart);
        //sets the frame visible
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        //sets the frame size
        frame2.setSize(900,700);
```

You will need to put such in a try catch block.

Remember that you will need a Jar file which allow you to import the necessary data from those JAR files for the charts.

Here is the complete set of coding shown below:

```
//method for top ten graph
private void topten()
{
    try
    {
        //connects to the database
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection)
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBName","root","password");
        //select statement calling data from the sales database
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM dbsales ORDER BY usold DESC LIMIT 10");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        //creates the graph object
        DefaultCategoryDataset ddataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            //retrieves data from the database for the graph
            ddataset.setValue(new Double(rs.getDouble("usold")), rs.getString("pbrand")  + " " + rs.getString("pname"),  rs.getString("pid"));
        }
         //generates the graph
         JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("Top 10 Selling Products", "Products", "Number of Units Sold", ddataset);
         //creates the graph title
        chart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.RED);
        //plots the graph
        CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.BLUE);
        //creates the frame 
        ChartFrame frame2 = new ChartFrame("Top 10 Selling Products", chart);
        //sets the frame visible
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        //sets the frame size
        frame2.setSize(900,700);
        }
     catch(Exception e)
    {
        //error message for when the graph cannot be generated
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error 111: Unable to identify and load best ten sellers for graph", "Database Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```